# Prove that algebraic structure $(\mathbb{R},*)$ is Abelian group..

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let * be defined in $\mathbb{R}$ in the following way:
$$a*b=\frac{a+b}{2}$$
where operation $+$ is addition in $\mathbb{R}$.
Is $(\mathbb{R},*)$ is Abelian group?

What I did is:
**1) we prove totality**
$$(\forall a,b\in\mathbb{R})\space\space a*b\in R$$
$$\Leftrightarrow\frac{a+b}{2}\in\mathbb{R}$$
and since we know that addition in $\mathbb{R}$ and division in $(\mathbb{R}-0)$ are both total operations $(2\neq0)$, we know that $*$ is also a total operation in $\mathbb{R}$.
**2) we prove associativity:**
$$(\forall a,b,c\in\mathbb{R})\space\space a*(b*c)=(a*b)*c$$
$$a*\Big(\frac{b+c}{2}\Big)=\frac{a+\frac{b+c}{2}}{2}=$$
$$=\frac{\frac{2a+b+c}{2}}{2}=\frac{\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{a+c}{2}}{2}=$$
$$=(a*b)*(a*c)\neq(a*b)*c$$
Since $*$ is not associative, $(\mathbb{R},*)$ is not even a semigroup, let alone Abelian group.
Am I right?

Comment: The idea is right, but the details get fuzzy at the end. You calculated $a\ast(b\ast c)$. Should also have calculated $(a\ast b)\ast c$, and then exhibited explicit $a,b,c$ for which they are not equal.

Comment: To disprove associativity, it's much easier to provide an explicit counterexample. Also, it seems like you're claiming $(a*b)*c \neq a*(b*c)$ for all real numbers $a, b, c$, which is untrue (e.g., if $a = b = c = 0$).

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you.

Comment: @manthanomen I see your point. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately,  that not equals sign is a bit begging the question...how do you know they are not equal?

However, this is easily resolved, by just picking some numbers and showing it doesn't work.   Say,  $a=4,b=6,c=10$.  Then $(4*6)*10=5*10=7.5$,  while $4*(6*10)=4*8=6$  and $6\ne 7.5$

Thus not associative, and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

You can see too that it doesn't exist a neutral element : indeed if you call $e$ a such element then
$$0*e=0\implies\frac{0+e}{2}=0\implies e=0$$ and $$1*e=1\implies\frac{1+e}{2}=1\implies e=1,$$ then $0=1$ leads to a contradiction and a such structure is not a group.